# Why am I getting the error 'Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern' when using pandas read_gbq

Tags: python, pandas, authentication, google-bigquery, service-accounts

I am trying to use python to read a view in BigQuery. I have previously used version 0.14.0 of pandas-gbq and authenticated using a service account by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(PATH_TO_JSON)

pd.read_gbq("""
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM BQ_VIEW,

                project_id="PROJECT_ID",
                dialect="standard",
                private_key=credentials
                )
```

Where PATH_TO_JSON, BQ_VIEW and PROJECT_ID have been filled in with the relevant info. This worked with no issues. However I am now working on another project that is using version 0.15.0 of pandas-gbq where the `private_key argument` is deprecated and has been replaced with `credentials`. Following [the guide](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html) on how to authenticate using the new credentials argument with a service account I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(PATH_TO_JSON)

pd.read_gbq("""
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM BQ_VIEW,

                project_id="PROJECT_ID",
                dialect="standard",
                credentials=credentials
                )
```

however when I run this I now get the error:

*Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern*

Is anyone able to advise me on where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that your view is referring to a table outside of BigQuery. Could you please mention where the external data is located, so that I can help you with the required permissions to be granted ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not related to the arguments. The error you are facing is due to improper IAM permissions to the service account . It seems you are trying to query a view which is referring to a table outside of BigQuery. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#permissions) says you need to grant your service account storage.objectViewer role in case your external table refers to a Cloud Storage file.